# WebSocket на js отвечает code 1006/ошибка 1006

Tags: javascript, websocket

Миссия: Для получения данных необходимо отправить запрос в виде строки JSON: {"operation":"getData"}
кто подскажет как исправить код 1006 приходит??

```
  window.onload = function () {
      const socket = new WebSocket("ws://185.246.65.199:8080");
      var status = document.querySelector("#status");
      const data = document.querySelector("#data");
    
    
      socket.onopen = function () {
        status.innerHTML = "cоединение установлено";
        socket.send(`JSON: {"operation":"getData"}`);
    
      };
    
      socket.onmessage = function (event) {
        console.log('event.data: ', event.data);
        data.innerHTML += `пришли данные: <b>${event.data}</b>`;
    
        let message = JSON.parse(event.data); //получение объекта в JSON-нотации
        status.innerHTML += `пришли данные: <b>${message}</b>`;
      };
    
      socket.onclose = function (event) {
        if (event.wasClean) {
          status.innerHTML = "cоединение закрыто";
        } else {
          status.innerHTML = "соединения как-то закрыто";
        }
        status.innerHTML += "<br>код: " + event.code + " причина: " + event.reason;
      };
    
      socket.onerror = function (event) {
        status.innerHTML = "ошибка " + event.message;
      };
    
      document.forms["messages"].onsubmit = function (event) {
        socket.send(`JSON: {"operation":"getData"}`);
      };
    };
```

Comment: исправил запрос на удалив  "JSON:"  -> `{"operation":"getData"}`

Answer (score 0):

исправил запрос на удалив "JSON:" -> {"operation":"getData"}